# How do I change serializeObject output format?

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to javascript and can't find the solution.
I have the following code.

```
<form class="edit-task-form">
        <legend>Create Task</legend>
        <label>Task</label>
        <input type="text" name="task" />
        <hr />
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Create</button>
    </form>
```

---

```
var taskDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
var task = new Task;
task.save(taskDetails, {
    success: function(task) {
        alert(task.toJSON());
    }
});
console.log(taskDetails);
```

---

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
    if(o[this.name] !==undefined) {
        if(!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    }
    else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
```

---

The output is:         Object {task: "fasdfasd"}

I would like it to be: Object {"task": "fasdfasd"}

How may I proceed to have "task" to appear in quotation marks?

Thanks a lot!

David

Comment: You do not need to manually add quotes to an object's property name, if converting to JSON it will be automatically there, if using the object to send data whatever underlying api will just send the property name as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this function:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
    if(o[this.name] !==undefined) {
        if(!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    }
    else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
```

you need to change it to this:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
    if(o['"'+this.name+'"'] !==undefined) {
        if(!o['"'+this.name+'"'].push) {
            o['"'+this.name+'"'] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o['"'+this.name+'"'].push(this.value || '');
    }
    else {
        o['"'+this.name+'"'] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
```

Just add to the key the quotes

Answer (score 0):

One solution :

```js
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
    if(o[this.name] !==undefined) {
        if(!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = ['"' + o[this.name] + '"' ]; //<---------
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    }
    else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
}
```

```js
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
    if(o[this.name] !==undefined) {
        if(!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = ['"' + o[this.name] + '"' ]; //<---------
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    }
    else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
}
var val = $('.edit-task-form').serializeObject();
document.write('<pre>'+ JSON.stringify( val , null , ' ') + '</pre>')
$('form').submit(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
document.write('<pre>'+ JSON.stringify( $(this).serializeArray() , null , ' ') + '</pre>')

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="edit-task-form">
        <legend>Create Task</legend>
        <label>Task</label>
        <input type="text" name="task" />
        <hr />
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Create</button>
    </form>
```